# How to get Position of RecyclerView on Retrofit Interface?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am trying to redirect the tag into the list of post associate with that particular tag and I am having problem on finding and passing the position of clicked RecyclerView on code given below

```
private final static String TAG_KEY = "1"; //How Do I Make it to take Position of RecyclerView so that post associate with that Tag can be opened

 ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);



    Call<Tag> call = apiService.getTag(TAG_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Tag>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Tag> call, Response<Tag> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            List<Post> tags = response.body().getTagPosts();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new PostListAdapter(tags, R.layout.list_item_post, getApplicationContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Tag> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

And how do I Call Interface on Adapter Instate of Intent

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TagAdapter.Tag_ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tagName.setText(Tags.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Recycle Click" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (position == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), TagToPostActivitiy.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
```

[List of Post Associated with Tag C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1RH.png)[List of Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capvR.png)

Comment: Which position do you want to access clicked? or lastVisible? or FirstVisible? your question is not clear.

Comment: I have attached the image of my app and i want to load the post associated with that tag listed on cardview. if you don't understand you can look into this link: http://api.technorio.com/

Answer (score 0):

your question isnt clear, if I get you correctly I assume you want send diffrent request depending on the current clicked recycleView item. so:
inside

```
public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

you are inflating some view, so just set it onClickListener:

```
    view v = LayoutInflater.from...
    v.setOnClickListener(
new MyOnClickListener() //pass here the event to click handler);
```

the clickListener should handle the api request with the correct position

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   int itemPosition = recyclerView.indexOfChild(v);
   //do your api request
}
```

Comment: I have implemented onClick Method but cannot call the Interface with different parameters.

Comment: so use onBindViewHolder, there you have the tag associated with the data..

Comment: As i edited the question and posted the onBindViewHolder Code, now I am concerned to pass  position of RecyclerView on this line of code: private final static String TAG_KEY = "1"; //how to get dynamic value or position of RecyclerView instate of 1, or anyway to make it dynamic. I am looking forward to your help.